# Javascript - insertAdjacentHTML from other file

Tags: javascript, insertadjacenthtml

I have a working JS script allowing me to insert some HTML elements. Now I'm looking to put the element to be inserted into a new file for my code to be cleaner and more flexible.
I've read that I could use the [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) but I'm not sure I understand the process.

Is there a way of doing so?

```js
let c = document.querySelectorAll("b > span > a");
let final = [];
for (elt of c) {
  if (elt.href.startsWith("http://something")) {
    final.push(elt.text);
    elt.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "afterend",
      `
            <div>
                <textarea
                    name="name"
                    cols=70
                    rows=2
                    wrap="hard"
                    style="vertical-align:text-top;color:black;font-family:sans-serif;resize:none;border-color:#EEEEEE">
                    ${elt.text}</textarea>
            <div/>
        `
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean you have two different html files with one JavaScript and you want to include `element` from one to another html file

Comment: so far, I only have a js file and I'm looking to export my <div> in a new html file.